# Log file for Symfony Command

Tags: php, shell, symfony

I want to save all of returns "Command" file in a log file

```
<?php

namespace LogicielBundle\Command\Cron;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MailRapportDometechCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
       $this
        ->setName('logiciel:mail_rapport_preparation_dometech')
    ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('. <bg=black;fg=white>Log color ...</>');

        $logFile = fopen('app/CommandLogs/MailRapportDometech/compteur.txt', 'w+');
        fputs($logFile, 'Test ... how to have $output data ?');
        fclose($logFile);

    }
}
```

And if possible , send me an e -mail error if there :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced the same issue, so i solved it like that :

Try to create handlers for specific logging channels to store logs in different files. here i've defined `security` channel as an example.

/!\ Your Command class must extend **ContainerAwareCommand** in order to use `$this->getContainer()`  to get this parameter `kernel.logs_dir`. As a result
this line `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.logs_dir')` will give you the path to your logs directory.

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

class CheckCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        // create a log channel
        $log = new Logger('security');
        $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.logs_dir').'/file.log', Logger::DEBUG));

        $log->addWarning('Foo');
        $log->addError('Bar');
}
```

Your log files will be stored at **/var/www/html/project-name/var/logs**

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `logger` service instead of writing into files directly. Just for these actions Monolog bundle was integrated into Symfony's core.

For example:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('logger')->error('your message');
```

And at your `app/config/config.yml` you can customize handlers for each level.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        applog:
            type: stream
            path: /path/to/your/file.log
            level: error
```

At the documentation you can find how to create email handler.

Comment: Thanks very much but this method cannot save PHP error :-/

Comment: You are not right. Symfony Debug component handles all errors and writes them to several channels. You can enable it on production without reporting to end-user Debug::enable(null, false);